# Navigation between screens in 2 different Stacks

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

I have 2 stacks, RootNavigator and AuthNavigator. Inside a `<NavigationContainer>`.

```js
<NavigationContainer>
  {token ? <RootNavigator /> : <AuthNavigator />}
</NavigationContainer>
```

The `RootNavigator.js` returns:

```js
return (
  <Stack.Navigator>
    <Stack.Screen name="Members">
  </Stack.Navigator>
)
```

The `AuthNavigator` returns:

```js
return (
  <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
    <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
  </Stack.Navigator>
);
```

My question is how can I go from the login screen to the members screen?

I've tried this:
`navigation.navigate('Members');` and `navigation.navigate('RootNavigator', {screens: 'Members'});`

Versions:

```
"@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.1.8",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
```

Comment: Could you add your react-navigation version?

Comment: @ridvanaltun done

Comment: If you nest 2 stack A and B in stack C. Then it can be possible.
Otherwise, you must add `<Stack.Screen name="Members">` into `AuthNavigator`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use redux or any other kind of state management for changing the token value. As soon as you change the token to TRUE, for example, the navigation container will have rootNavigator instead of authNavigator and the screen will change.

Comment: But how can I change with redux? I searched it but I couldn't find it. Can you explain to me or drop an example?

Comment: When you login, you should change "token" value in redux store.
So, for example, you have an action in redux called onSigin. This action changes your token state to TRUE. So when the user logs in, you call this action and "token" becomes true. Then in the navigation, <RootNavigator />  will be used.